# Java Quick Sort Optimization

Tags: java

I have three classes. Each creates an array of 1000 int values.

- class a: uses QuickSort
- class b: uses QuickSort until the size of each partition is <10 then executes InsertSort for sorting the smaller partitions.
- class c: (this is the one I'm having trouble with): same as class b except executes InsertSort on the whole almost sorted array.

It would seem that class c is only a slight variation of the code in class b (which basically adds to class a). I just don't really know HOW to make this happen... Help! Thanks in advanced...

Class a:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSort {

private static final Random random = new Random();
private static final int RANDOM_INT_RANGE = 9999;

private static int[] randomArray(int size) {

    // Randomize data (array)
    final int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = random.nextInt(RANDOM_INT_RANGE);
    }
    return arr;
}

// Sort
private static void sort(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0)
        sortInPlace(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private static void sortInPlace(int[] arr, int left, int right) {

    if (left >= right)
        return; // sorted

    final int range = right - left + 1;
    int pivot = random.nextInt(range) + left;

    int newPivot = partition(arr, left, right, pivot);

    sortInPlace(arr, left, newPivot - 1);
    sortInPlace(arr, newPivot + 1, right);

}

private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right, int pivot) {

    int pivotVal = arr[pivot];
    swapArrayVals(arr, pivot, right);

    int storeIndex = left;
    for (int i = left; i <= (right - 1); i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivotVal) {
            swapArrayVals(arr, i, storeIndex);
            storeIndex++;
        }
    }

    swapArrayVals(arr, storeIndex, right);

    return storeIndex;
}

private static void swapArrayVals(int[] arr, int from, int to) {
    int fromVal = arr[from];
    int toVal = arr[to];
    arr[from] = toVal;
    arr[to] = fromVal;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long StartTime = System.nanoTime();

    // Array size
    int[] arr = randomArray(1000);
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);

    // Print original data (array)
    System.out.println("The starting/unsorted array: \n"
            + Arrays.toString(arr));

    sort(arr);

    // check the result
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    if (Arrays.equals(arr, copy)) {
        System.out.println("The ending/sorted array: \n"
                + Arrays.toString(arr));

        // print time
        long TotalTime = System.nanoTime() - StartTime;
        System.out.println("Total elapsed time (milliseconds) " + "is: "
                + TotalTime);
    }

}
}
```

Class b:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class OptQSort1 {
private static final Random random = new Random();
private static final int RANDOM_INT_RANGE = 9999;

private static int[] randomArray(int size) {

    // Randomize data (array)
    final int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = random.nextInt(RANDOM_INT_RANGE);
    }
    return arr;
}

// Sort
private static void sort(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0)
        sortInPlace(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private static void sortInPlace(int[] arr, int left, int right) {

    boolean insertionSortCalled = false;

    // OptQSort1:
    int size = right - left + 1;
    if (size < 10 && !insertionSortCalled) {
        insertionSortCalled = true;
        insertionSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    if (left >= right)
        return; // sorted

    final int range = right - left + 1;
    int pivot = random.nextInt(range) + left;

    int newPivot = partition(arr, left, right, pivot);

    sortInPlace(arr, left, newPivot - 1);
    sortInPlace(arr, newPivot + 1, right);

}

private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right, int pivot) {

    int pivotVal = arr[pivot];
    swapArrayVals(arr, pivot, right);

    int storeIndex = left;
    for (int i = left; i <= (right - 1); i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivotVal) {
            swapArrayVals(arr, i, storeIndex);
            storeIndex++;
        }
    }

    swapArrayVals(arr, storeIndex, right);

    return storeIndex;
}

private static void swapArrayVals(int[] arr, int from, int to) {
    int fromVal = arr[from];
    int toVal = arr[to];
    arr[from] = toVal;
    arr[to] = fromVal;
}

public static void insertionSort(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int in, out;

    for (out = left + 1; out <= right; out++) {
        int temp = arr[out];
        in = out;

        while (in > left && arr[in - 1] >= temp) {
            arr[in] = arr[in - 1];
            --in;
        }
        arr[in] = temp;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long StartTime = System.nanoTime();

    // Array size
    int[] arr = randomArray(1000);
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);

    // Print original data (array)
    System.out.println("The starting/unsorted array: \n"
            + Arrays.toString(arr));

    sort(arr);

    // check the result
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    if (Arrays.equals(arr, copy)) {
        System.out.println("The ending/sorted array: \n"
                + Arrays.toString(arr));

        // print time
        long TotalTime = System.nanoTime() - StartTime;
        System.out.println("Total elapsed time (milliseconds) " + "is: "
                + TotalTime);
    }
}

}
```

Class c:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class OptQSort2 {

private static final Random random = new Random();
private static final int RANDOM_INT_RANGE = 9999;

private static int[] randomArray(int size) {

    // Randomize data (array)
    final int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = random.nextInt(RANDOM_INT_RANGE);
    }
    return arr;
}

// Sort
private static void sort(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 0)
        sortInPlace(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    insertionSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private static void sortInPlace(int[] arr, int left, int right) {

    // OptQSort2:
    int size = right - left + 1;

    if (size < 10)
        return;

    if (left >= right)
        return; // sorted

    final int range = right - left + 1;
    int pivot = random.nextInt(range) + left;

    int newPivot = partition(arr, left, right, pivot);

    sortInPlace(arr, left, newPivot - 1);
    sortInPlace(arr, newPivot + 1, right);

}

private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right, int pivot) {

    int pivotVal = arr[pivot];
    swapArrayVals(arr, pivot, right);

    int storeIndex = left;
    for (int i = left; i <= (right - 1); i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivotVal) {
            swapArrayVals(arr, i, storeIndex);
            storeIndex++;
        }
    }

    swapArrayVals(arr, storeIndex, right);

    return storeIndex;
}

private static void swapArrayVals(int[] arr, int from, int to) {
    int fromVal = arr[from];
    int toVal = arr[to];
    arr[from] = toVal;
    arr[to] = fromVal;
}

public static void insertionSort(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int in, out;

    for (out = left + 1; out <= right; out++) {
        int temp = arr[out];
        in = out;

        while (in > left && arr[in - 1] >= temp) {
            arr[in] = arr[in - 1];
            --in;
        }
        arr[in] = temp;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Start the clock
    long StartTime = System.nanoTime();

    // Array size
    int[] arr = randomArray(1000);
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);

    // Print original data (array)
    System.out.println("The starting/unsorted array: \n"
            + Arrays.toString(arr));

    sort(arr);

    // check the result
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    if (Arrays.equals(arr, copy)) {
        System.out.println("The ending/sorted array: \n"
                + Arrays.toString(arr));

        // print time
        long TotalTime = System.nanoTime() - StartTime;
        System.out.println("Total elapsed time (milliseconds) " + "is: "
                + TotalTime);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create class c copy class b and then** change it in the following way:
Add instance variable insertionSortCalled so you don't call insertion sort multiple times in different recursive calls

```
 boolean insertionSortCalled= false;
```

And change this part to the following: insertionSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);

```
private static void sortInPlace(int[] arr, int left, int right) {

// OptQSort1:
int size = right - left + 1;
**if (size < 10 && !insertionSortCalled){**
      **insertionSortCalled=true;**
      **insertionSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);**
  }

if (left >= right)
    return; // sorted

final int range = right - left + 1;
int pivot = random.nextInt(range) + left;

int newPivot = partition(arr, left, right, pivot);

sortInPlace(arr, left, newPivot - 1);
sortInPlace(arr, newPivot + 1, right);
```

}

Comment: I just reposted my classes... Thank you for the response. Please let me know if I'm still not on track!

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't precise. By change class b i meant: **In order to create class c** change class b etc... Also boolean insertionSortCalled must be declared  at class level not in the method.
The easiest way check if you are on track is run a test to check if array is sorted. A simple for loop comparing if element[i]>= element[i-1] would suffice.

Comment: Uh oh.. Read that wrong! So basically I just have class b & c swapped? But if I'm understanding correctly I also need to declare insertionSortCalled (currently in class c, but really needs to be class b) at the class level - making it static?

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that class c just implements insertion-sort, with no quick-sort at all, right?

Then in principle, class c could just be class b, with this line:

```
    sort(arr);
```

changed to this:

```
    insertionSort(arr, 0, arr.length);
```

(And then you'd want to start stripping out a lot of code — removing methods that are never called, modifying the `insertionSort` method to assume that `left` is `0` and `right` is `arr.length` rather than requiring them to be specified, renaming the `insertionSort` method to `sort`, etc.)

By the way, class c is actually much easier than the classes you've already managed to create. You probably just need to get some sleep. You'll have no problem with it in the morning. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! You're probably right about the sleep... ha To clarify though- my specific requirements state the following: "execute quick sort until partition's size gets lower than a given cutoff value [I chose 10], then execute insert sort on the whole 'almost sorted' array." I read that as I still need to use quick sort but then instead of using insert sort on each of the partitions (as done in b) use it on the whole array? Maybe I am just tired...

Comment: @javaNewb37: Now understanding the requirement for class c, and having now looked more closely at what class B is doing . . . in class B, you call `insertionSort` in two places: once in `sortInPlace`, and once in `sort`. For class B, you shouldn't be calling it in `sort`. (If you find that you *need* to call it in `sort` (that is, that the result isn't sorted otherwise), then that means you have a bug in either `sortInPlace` or `partition`.) Conversely, for class C, you shouldn't be calling it in `sortInPlace`: if `sortInPlace` finds that its partition-size is less than 10, then it should just

Comment: return, and let `sort`'s final call to `insertionSort` handle everything.

Comment: By the way, your logic for setting `StartTime`, `FinishTime`, and `TotalTime` is wrong. You need to set them all inside `main`; as it is now, they all get set before `main` even runs!

Comment: Thank you for the responses @ruakh! I really appreciate your input. I think I considered all of your comments in my corrections. (especially the bit about start/finish time... WOW! I must have been more tired than I thought!) Thanks again!